# Why does my Cygwin installation has a bad $PATH?

Tags: cygwin

I've just installed Cygwin on my computer. If I type `echo $PATH` I can see this output:

```
$ export $PATH
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `(x86)/NVIDIA': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Corporation/PhysX/Common:%CommonProgramFiles%/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Shared/Windows': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Live:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/OpenVPN/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `(x86)/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/dev/java/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin:/cygdrive/c/programs/Java/jdk7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/edem/.lein/bin': not a valid identifier
```

It seems that there is some formatting issue here but I can't put my fingers on it. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to export the *value* of PATH. Just export the variable:

```
export PATH
```

Or you're just confusing `export` with `echo`.

Comment: I get no result if I do `export PATH`.

Comment: I guess I didn't make that edit fast enough. Are your trying to `export PATH` or `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Okey this was the problem. Now it is ok, thank you.

Comment: I can't accept until my question is at least 10 minutes old.